# A trajectory along vs across vs through three points

Tags: vocabulary

If I'm going from a point A to B and then to C... (Or with events of your life).
Would you say?

- Along, across or through the three points.
- Along, across or through the trajectory/path.

Maybe another synonym.
Or with events of your life.

Comment: I would say through points, and along a path. Trajectory sounds too technical, so for life events path is a better word.

Comment: Take your choice based on the broader context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually enhance the path between points

"Traverse" can be used to indicate traveling over or through something, usually over a type of terrain. It can, however, be used to describe a path.

Traversing from A through B to C

> • Traversing between the three points.
>   • Traveling between the three points.

There are many concepts rooted in "transit" such as transgression (religion and law) and transition (a favourite in engineering and computing)

*Odd note:- in religion the Latin **[Transitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitus)** means the passage from death to life*

However for life we often substitute journey for path

> The **journey** from birth through parenthood to death can be an enriching
>   one.

A common term used in GIS / Mapping for the path between temporal events is "track" So in this case we could say

Tracking from A through B to C

However in temporal logic "transition path" is favoured.

Many disciplines use a jargon specific format.

For all round use it is probably best to use "path" with a description as in

> Along the temporal events path.
>   **Along the path of temporal events.**
>   The path through temporal events.

Comment: What if they are temporal events during his life?